# Will arcing occur if the two sources are isolated?

Tags: pcb, high-voltage, arc

If I have two tracks on a PCB, that are 0.6mm apart, will the 230V arc across to the 3.3V PCB track?

The two supplies are isolated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu7Gub.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Voltages are potential differences so, you need to indicate where the return paths are for proper analysis. If the two sources and their respective return circuits are both individually isolated from earth then there should be no arcing.

Comment: Keep in mind, there could be arcing, if some poor unsuspecting victim bridges the gap with a moist finger.

Comment: I would put a very large asterisk on "isolated" if you want to override the IPC MEC guideline (1.25mm in this case).  Can you guarantee that nothing will ever be connected to the circuit to give both a common ground?  I think you might also have to treat the 3.3V side as 230V with respect to ground as well.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the 3.3V trace has much more than 230V (like kV of isolation if mains as mains can have kV faults) and every part of that circuit that is connected to 3.3V has isolation, then you probably would not get arcing. Keep in mind you would have to isolate 3.3V from ground and also have it's entire circuit on a power supply that has isolation. The entire circuit connected to 3.3V would need to be isolated and insulated, if arcing would occur, the 3.3V circuit could be lit up to 230V. Any digital comms to anything connected to the 3.3V circuit would need to be isolated. I would say, if you felt comfortable shorting 230V directly to the 3.3V line, then it would be safe.

In essence, you would need to treat the 3.3V circuit like it could be powered to 230V. If you were to run this by an NRTL, they may not pass you and you would definatley have a lot of explaining to do to prove that this scheme was safe if using this in a product or they may just say no, increase the spacing.

Arcing can occur if dust or other pollution were to help bridge the gap. The easier way would be to just increase the space or provide a insulative barrier between the two voltages to make it safe.